# rasterFromXYZ generates an unexpected blank line

Tags: raster, image-conversion

I converted a raster to a dataframe by rasterToPoints, then converted it back to raster using rasterFromXYZ. An unexpected blank line appeared on the second raster as shown below. Any way to avoid this?

[image: Original raster vs. the raster from rasterFromXYZ]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For example you can do (reproducible example)

```
library(raster)
f <- system.file("external/test.grd", package="raster")
r <- raster(f)
v <- as.matrix(r)
v <- v * 2
x <- setValues(r, v)
```

But in most cases it is not advisable to go this route as you can do almost any operation on the Raster objects themselves.

With your data I do:

```
r <- raster("bv2.tif")
x <- rasterToPoints(r)
z <- rasterFromXYZ(x)
e <- extent(-121.4,-114.6,49,50.4)
zoom(z, e)
```

And there is no white line. Zooming in further does not show an irregularity either. So this may be a problem with the tool you used to produce your maps.

This is confirmed by

```
sum(values(z) != values(r), na.rm=TRUE)
# [1] 0
cellStats(r, 'countNA')
# [1] 2130763
cellStats(z, 'countNA')
# [1] 2130763
```

Comment: This workflow may not apply to my case as I need to keep the original v values unchanged. Here is my raster file: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B9Luzv8umx5mMnZpeTl0X1lPLTg/view?usp=sharing

Comment: If you do not want to change the values, what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: To attach more columns to the dataframe then to generate multiple raster layers.

Comment: The problem occurs with the full range. If I reduce the extent to that particular area (-121.4,-114.6,49,50.4), the blank line disappears.

Comment: it is unlikely that you should go this route to "to generate multiple raster layers". Your display problem seems to be that, a problem with display, and we do not know how you are doing that.

Comment: Ok, I will try a different way to do that. Thanks a lot for your help. Raster is a great package. I use it all the time.